# Installing pep8 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pep8

Trying to install pep8 on Windows 7 machine. So I can use SublimeLiter for Sublime Text to lint through python scripts.

Did clear install of Python34. Checked in *pip* and *system path* options.

Tried:

1. Ran `python pip install pep8`. Output: `python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
2. Downloaded get-pip.py from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html and ran `C:/Python34/get-pip.py install pep8`. Output: 

   `Collecting install
   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement install
   Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable
   (use --allow-external install to allow).
   No distributions at all found for install`
3. `C:/Python34/get-pip.py install pep8`. Output: command not found.

Any suggestions how can one install PEP8 on windows?

Comment: what gives `python -m pip install pep8` ?

Comment: It worked! I am surprised I didn't found this simple option digging through the dozen official pages. If you create an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Neitsa suggested, one should use -m (module) option for Windows in order to install modules via PiP.

Here is the working solution in CMD:

```
python -m pip install pep8
```

Credits goes to Naitsa.